# MATLAB Plot: modifying point position on y plane

Tags: matlab

I have this line of code in MATLAB, which sets these vectors:

```
x = [2 12 3 8 1 9 2; -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3]
x =
 2  12  3  8  1  9  2
-3  -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

Considering the first row as points in y-plane and second row as x-axis in MATLAB plot

Now what line of code in MATLAB will take the maximum number in the first row and set at the middle(0) point in x-axis which will make it look like this

```
x =
 9   2  2  12 3  8  1
-3  -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

Please any idea is appreciated, I don't know how best to ask this question, I'm actually trying to edit a plot in MATLAB.

Comment: You question is still unclear. Do you want to change the values of first row, so 12 will become 0? Or do you want to move x axis from 0 to 12?

Comment: the first row are points on Y plane, so i want to make the maximum point which is 12 to be on 0(deg) in x axis no longer on -2. i don't know how to add a picture so i can explain further. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
x = [2 12 3 8 1 9 2; -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3];
[~,idx] = max(x(1,:));
x(1,:) = circshift(x(1,:),[0 (length(x)+1)/2-idx]);
```

Output:

```
x =

     9     2     2    12     3     8     1
    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3
```